# How should I add a project dependency to a limited set of subprojects?

Tags: gradle

I would like to add a certain project dependency to various subproject starting with a specific name.

I tried this

```
subprojects.findAll { project -> project.name.startsWith("myproject-sample") }.each { project ->
   dependencies {
      //compile project(":myproject-core")
   }
}
```

but it gives

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'myproject'.

> Could not find method call() for arguments [:myproject-core] on project ':myproject-sample-hello-world'.
```

When I do this

```
subprojects {
   dependencies {
      compile project(":myproject-core")
   }
}
```

it seems to work. But it adds the dep to all subprojects.

How should I add a project dep to a limited set of subprojects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A clean solution is:

```
def sampleProjects = subprojects.findAll { it.name.startsWith("sample") }

configure(sampleProjects) {
    dependencies {
        compile project(":myproject-core")
    }
}
```

Or:

```
subprojects {
    if (project.name.startsWith("sample")) {
        dependencies {
            compile project(":myproject-core")
        }
    }
}
```

Both snippets assume that the sample projects have already had the `java` plugin applied (otherwise add `apply plugin: "java"` before the `dependencies` block).

Answer (score 0):

The `subprojects` method delegates to an instance of the `Project` interface for each subproject, which is why your second example works (`Project` has a method called `dependencies()`). The `each` method however is simply passed a `Project` object as an argument. You then need to call the `dependencies()` method on that object. This requires a simple syntactical change.

```
subprojects.findAll { project -> 
    project.name.startsWith("myproject-sample") 
}.each { project -> 
    project.dependencies {
        compile project(":myproject-core")
    }
}
```